# nodejs puppeteer cant download image file with special characters in URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, puppeteer

I have two images I want to download on my local computer:

- [https://45football.com/assets/resources/1134/medium/1035-nöggi-subliga-cf.jpg](https://45football.com/assets/resources/1134/medium/1035-n%C3%B6ggi-subliga-cf.jpg)
- https://45football.com/assets/resources/675/medium/580-maritimo-cf.jpg

As you can see the first image as a special character in it's url `ö`, but is still a valid url you can visit online.

I'm trying to download both images using a node.js puppeteer ( version "5.5.0",) script I made, it tries to download with the following code:

```
function download(url, destination, cb) {
  return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
    try {
      var file = fs.createWriteStream(destination);
      var request = https.get(url, function (response) {
        response.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', function () {
          file.close(cb);  // close() is async, call cb after close completes.
          resolve(true)
        });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('err saving file:', err)
      reject()
    }
  });
}

async function debugDownload(){
  let broken_imgUrl='https://45football.com/assets/resources/1134/medium/1035-nöggi-subliga-cf.jpg';
  let broken_imgSavePath='/home/martin/Documents/projects/broken.jpg';
  download(broken_imgUrl, broken_imgSavePath, function (x) { console.log('img download done'); });

  let good_imgUrl='https://45football.com/assets/resources/675/medium/580-maritimo-cf.jpg'
  let good_imgSavePath='/home/martin/Documents/projects/good.jpg';
  await download(good_imgUrl, good_imgSavePath, function (x) { console.log('img download done'); });
}
```

after running `debugDownload()`, the file `good.jpg` is downloaded fine, but `broken.jpg` is only 707 bytes and I cant open it, making me think there's something wrong with my download function where it doesn work for URL's with special characters in it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is earlier versions of nodejs do not have encodeURI by default, as such we get a 404 not found. Just add encodeURI(url). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

```
function download(url, destination, cb) {
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
      try {
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(destination);
        var request = https.get(encodeURI(url), function (response) { // modified
          response.pipe(file);
          file.on('finish', function () {
            file.close(cb);  // close() is async, call cb after close completes.
            resolve(true)
          });
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('err saving file:', err)
        reject()
      }
    });
  }
  
  async function debugDownload(){
    let broken_imgUrl='https://45football.com/assets/resources/1134/medium/1035-nöggi-subliga-cf.jpg';
    let broken_imgSavePath='/home/martin/Documents/projects/broken.jpg';
    download(broken_imgUrl, broken_imgSavePath, function (x) { console.log('img download done'); });
  
    let good_imgUrl='https://45football.com/assets/resources/675/medium/580-maritimo-cf.jpg'
    let good_imgSavePath='/home/martin/Documents/projects/good.jpg';
    await download(good_imgUrl, good_imgSavePath, function (x) { console.log('img download done'); });
  }
```

I do not know which version of node you are using.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by uri encoding the url with special characters, works that way